# Close the menu when clicked anywhere in body area outside dropdown menu

Tags: jquery, menu, drop-down-menu, hide

I am trying to implement this menu in my web site :

Here is the code :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.fixedMenu.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fixedMenu_style1.css" />
        <script>
        $('document').ready(function(){
            $('.menu').fixedMenu();
        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">More Examples<span class="arrow"></span></a>

                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Plugins and jQuery Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Prototype Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Mootools Examples</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Javascript Examples</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Plugins<span class="arrow"></span></a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Galleries</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">DropDown Menus</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Content Slider</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">LightBox</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

and the code for .js file is :

```
(function($){
    $.fn.fixedMenu=function(){
        return this.each(function(){
            var menu= $(this);
            menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function(){
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
            else{
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
            })
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

I want the active menu to be closed when someone clicks anywhere in the body area....

I am a newbie to jquery :-) , pls help

thanks

Sandeep

Edit : after your final comments this is how the code looks .

```
$("html").click(function() {
   menu.find('.active').removeClass('active');
});


(function($){
    $.fn.fixedMenu=function(){
        return this.each(function(){

            var menu= $(this);

            menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click', function (event) {
              event.stopPropagation();
            });                               

            $("body:not(.menu)").hover(function(){ $(".menu").find('.active').removeClass('active');})
            menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click',function(){
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass('active')){
                $(this).parent().removeClass('active');
            }
            else{
                $(this).parent().parent().find('.active').removeClass('active');
                $(this).parent().addClass('active');
            }
            })
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

but still no success....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for hover :

```
$("body:not(.menu)").hover(function(){ $(".menu").find('.active').removeClass('active');})
```

Edit :

Bind a click event to html to capture any click made, and make it hide the menu

```
$("html").click(function() {
   menu.find('.active').removeClass('active');
});
```

Then override that on your menu's click event using .stopPropagation();

```
menu.find('ul li > a').bind('click', function (event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Using the above line of code the drop-down menu is getting hidden when we are hovering outside the menu block , but what i am willing to do is hide the drop-down menu when someone  [ clicks ] on the body area outside the drop-down menu ...

Comment: nops...... if i change it to [ click ] from  [ hover ] the dropdown is infact not being displayed...

Comment: oohh yeah because .menu is included in the body ... mhhh 2 sec il give you a solution

Answer (score 0):

Jquery Drop Down Menu

The **on click** action on the needs to be captured to close the open meny either clicked on the same link or anywhere on body should close the menu

In my case i wanted to close a drop down menu if its clicked on primary link or outside the link i.e. anywhere on the html/body

http://jsfiddle.net/austinnoronha/k2Lwj/

```
var toggleClick = function(){

    var divObj = $(this).next();
    var nstyle = divObj.css("display");

    if(nstyle == "none"){
        divObj.slideDown(false,function(){
            $("html").bind("click",function(){
                divObj.slideUp();
                $("html").unbind("click");
            });
        });
    }
};

$(".clickme").click(toggleClick);
```